# Disable UIWebView DiskImageCache

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiwebview, docx

When loading documents that contain images (such as a *Microsoft Word docx* file), the UIWebView will always cache the images when it receives a memory warning regardless of the cache policy.

Following, there's a sample code snippet:

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:1024 * 1024
                                              diskCapacity:0
                                              diskPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"URLCache"]];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.its.swinburne.edu.au/about/projects/templates/TechnicalSpecificationTemplatev1.1-[ProjectName]-[ver]-[YYYYMMDD].docx"] 
                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData 
                    timeoutInterval:10];
```

Under these circumstances, if a memory warning occurs, a new folder is created in the **tmp** directory of the app, usually named **DiskImageCache-random_suffix** and all the images in the opened document are saved here.

After the *UIWebView* loads a new request, if I call

```
[sharedCache removeAllCachedResponses];
```

these temporary images are removed.

The only way to prevent caching the images is to call

```
[NSClassFromString(@"WebCache") performSelector:@selector(setDisabled:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

but this means using private API.

Is there an "Apple friendly" way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out after looking into the WebKit "undocumented" preferences. With the following setting, it is possible to disable DiskImageCache for the entire lifetime of the application:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"WebKitDiskImageCacheEnabled"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: I have just tested this solution with iOS 7.1.1 and uploaded the sample code on [GitHub](https://github.com/objectiveself/WebViewImageCacheControl).
Note that the setting will take effect next time you launch the app, when the UIWebView is initialized.

Comment: @DrMickeyLauer, try WebKitOfflineWebApplicationCacheEnabled