# WKWebView shows pdf inside a border, I don't want the border

Tags: swift, pdf, wkwebview

I have a custom view that adds a WKWebView like this:

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    loadWebView()
}

func loadWebView() {
    pdfWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)

    pdfWebView.navigationDelegate = self
    pdfWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pdfWebView.isHidden = true
    self.addSubview(pdfWebView)
    ... add constrains to self anchors - top, left, right, bottom
}
```

When loads finishes, I have this:

```
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.8, execute: {
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        webView.isHidden = false
        webView.isOpaque = true
        webView.adjustInsets()
    })
}
```

I had to adjust the insets, because on iPhone X, sometimes the pdf sticked to the bottom, instead to the top.

```
extension WKWebView {
    func adjustInsets() {
        parentViewController?.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        scrollView.contentInset = .zero
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = .zero
        scrollView.contentOffset = .zero
    }
}
```

The result is this:

There is a gray border.

[image: full border]

I have tried this:

1. setting view's, pdfWebView and pdfWebView.scrollView  **background** with .white or .clear
2. `webView.isOpaque = false` ( this is the single one that removes the bottom part of the gray - but not the border)

[image]

3. I have used an extension to set the .clear color to all child views

   ```
   extension UIView {
       func clearBackgrounds() {
           self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
           for subview in self.subviews {
               subview.clearBackgrounds()
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Nothing works to **remove the border**. I can not edit the pdf, because this one is downloaded from ws and used in multiple apps.

Comment: Hi, could you try to init the WebView with `UIScreen.main.bounds` instead of `.zero` ?

Comment: No, it does not work.  in `webView(::didFinish)` everything is displayed again. `pdfWebView` takes the part of the screen as constrains put it. The `WKWebView(frame: )` could have any frame. It does not matter. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution : 
I found a trick to do this, I think you can use this with pdf that has white background. It has the idea, you can manipulate this with your design.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
let urlString = "http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"
let string = "<html><body marginwidth=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" style=\"background-color: transparent\"><embed width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" name=\"plugin\" src=\"\(urlString)\" type=\"application/pdf\"></body></html>"
webView.loadHTMLString(string, baseURL: nil)
```

Edit : If you want to use this with base64 encoded pdf data, you can use with that :

```
var pdfBase64String = "" //Your pdf data
if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: pdfBase64String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
        pdfWebView.load(decodedData, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
}
```

Old Answer : Turning off "WebKitDiskImageCacheEnabled" can be fix this problem.
Can you try this before load the pdf ?

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "WebKitDiskImageCacheEnabled")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525065/disable-uiwebview-diskimagecache. This was a solution for UIWebView, I am using WKWebView. I've tried it, also without success.

Comment: Got it. I tried to reproduce your problem with example pdfs but it didn't happen. Also can you upload high-res screenshot 'cause I cannot see nothing.

Comment: Uploaded. I really hate when those occupy all window, but hopefully, now the border can be seen. :)

Comment: This works as it is posted. The problem that I have is that pdf is loaded as Data, and I didn't discover a way to put it into this generated html. Although, I am replacing this custom view to use PDFKit for iOS 11 + with the fallback to WKWebKit for earlier versions of iOS. PDFKit does not show any border, and it seems to be the right way to work with pdfs.

Comment: Of course it can be good way to use PDF. But if you want to use your data in html, you can use it as base64 encoded string, it'll fix.

Comment: I've accepted the answer and given you the bounty. Thanks! It is working, but the only problem that I can see now is when I have 2 pages. It only shows me one page. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes you're right! I didn't see this because my example had one page, sorry about that. I'm editing my last answer and it's proper solution I guess. I tried this and it's working. Thank you.

Comment: The solution worked for me, but the pdf shrinks to fit into the webview without scrolling. I removed the "height=100%" inside embed tag and it worked for me.

Comment: @Emre Using the pdf bse64 encoded pdf data I still get a grey border all around the pdf :(

Answer (score 0):

I will use PDFKit for iOS 11 + in this custom view with the fallback to WKWebView for earlier versions. PDFView does not have any gray background.